# The Read API v3.0 stopped returning the correct angle values

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

We've been using Azure Cognitive Services, namely the Read API. Around June, we upgraded from v2.0 to the v3.0 API.
The JSON object returned by the API contains the orientation angle for each page. A few days ago, we've noticed that the API is now returning the angle as 0, regardless of the page orientation.

This does not raise an error *per se*, yet it impacts our algorithm downstream, and so I'm looking for feedback from other users/Microsoft employees on this matter.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT

Here is a redacted version of one of the offending documents:

[image: Redacted version of rotated document]

Here is a sample of the JSON response we obtained after processing a non-redacted *PDF* version of the same document:

[image: JSON response]

Comment: Can you please share the sample image that you are trying.

Comment: Also if possible please share the response JSON.

Answer (score 0):

In [Read API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/upgrade-api-versions#api-response-json) v3.0 API we could see the angle and the range has been changed from 0 - 360 degrees to -180 to 180 degrees. Please find the snapshot for response JSON.

[image]

Comment: Can you please share the location of the Cognitive Services resource you used? Also, did you try an image or a PDF file?

Comment: I did an experiment with an image, and I get a correct angle value, but using a PDF of the same document yields the 0 angle I reported.

Comment: We have forwarded to the product team and will update ASAP.